# Batch replace a language file using grep?

Tags: batch-file, replace, grep, find

I am trying to find/replace a long language file:

```
 $_LANG['accountinformation'] = "Account Information";
 $_LANG['accountstatistics'] = "Account Statistics";
```

to become:

```
 $_LANG['accountinformation'] = "Informations du compte";
 $_LANG['accountstatistics'] = "Statistiques du compte";
```

knowing that I have the whole translation in a file like this:

```
Informations du compte
Statistiques du compte
```

Is there a way to replace these phrases with a text editor such as BBedit using grep or something instead of copy/pasting each one of them by hand?

Comment: What you're looking for (I think) is `sed`

Comment: Notepad.exe "Replace" (Ctrl-H) "replace all"-Button ?

Comment: Has this solved your query yet?

Comment: Thanks tripleee and Matt for the answers: This won't probably work for me, the document which need language replaced has blank lines and also #notes between lines, and the translated document comes as one block. I would like to keep the layout of the original language.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using a batch/vbs hybrid script:

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :FindReplace "Account Statistics" "Statistiques du compte" Thefile.txt
call :FindReplace "Account Information"  "Informations du compte" Thefile.txt

exit /b 

:FindReplace <findstr> <replstr> <file>
set tmp="%temp%\tmp.txt"
If not exist %temp%\_.vbs call :MakeReplace
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "%3" /s /b /a-d /on') do (
  for /f "usebackq" %%b in (`Findstr /mic:"%~1" "%%a"`) do (
    echo(&Echo Replacing "%~1" with "%~2" in file %%~nxa
    <%%a cscript //nologo %temp%\_.vbs "%~1" "%~2">%tmp%
    if exist %tmp% move /Y %tmp% "%%~dpnxa">nul
  )
)
del %temp%\_.vbs
exit /b

:MakeReplace
>%temp%\_.vbs echo with Wscript
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo set args=.arguments
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo .StdOut.Write _
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo Replace(.StdIn.ReadAll,args(0),args(1),1,-1,1)
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo end with
```

Change thefile.txt to your filename. Save the script as replace.cmd from a text editor and run it from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to say that the files are aligned -- there is exactly one string definition per line in the English file, and the French contains the translation equivalences in the same order, one per line -- then a simple `paste` with some postprocessing should do it.

```
paste strings.def fr.txt |
sed 's/"[^"]*";\t\(.*\)/"\1";/' >output.txt
```

If your `sed` dialect doesn't support `\t` for tab, you'll have to supply a literal tab (<kbd>ctrl-v tab</kbd> in many shells).